# Tor through Tails redirecting sites to Google

Tags: tails

Tails redirects some sites to Google, sites that work fine with Tor browser through Windows. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I've never experienced this under Tails. Can you provide any more details?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Tails OS but if it has any proxy settings edit them to expect *.google.com

Google can see your real ip but trust google

google always track ip addresses to avoid any attacks

sorry for my trashy grammer :D

Comment: This doesn't seem like an especially good idea and under Tails google will not be able to see your real IP address since it uses iptables to enforce Tor usage.